# Using Rails with backend server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase

I'm new to developing Ruby On Rails but have started creating a website for a mobile application that my friends are making.  They are storing all of the data (Usernames, photos, posts...) on firebase (firebase.com) so we can all access it.

In broad terms I'm trying to figure out how to implement a lot of this with Ruby On Rails.  Looking at most tutorials for rails, it seems like they assume the website has its own database.  For instance when a user signs in, I use the user model to save the name, email and password.  However this saves it to the rails database and not to firebase where all of the current usernames and passwords are stored.  Should I ignore the standard rails method for user authentication and just sign the user into firebase or should I save this data to the rails database.  If so, how to I keep that database in sync with firebase?

Comment: You can build a rails app without its own database, if you already have all your data in an external DB, you are probably better off using that directly (especially since firebase seems to have a good API). Once you have decided on your strategy, you can ask here if you have specific issues.

Comment: Using firebase DB in a rails app is a bad idea because the beauty of rails lies in ORM which is not possible using firebase DB. Yes, we can use firebase APIs to perform CRUD operations but is your database has some sort of relational data than you have to do multiple firebase API requests to update data. Transactions are not supported using REST APIs and you have to do all this yourself.